# Load interface from remote assembly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c++-cli, client-server

I am currently developing client-server application.
It should load interfaces from modules and show them inside of its own window.
But sometimes I need to plugin remote module.
Can I run form from module (with all actions working) without loading module file on disk?
Thank you.

Comment: Adriano: thank you. So, I will download it with WebClient, but to the memory? One more question: can I load only one class(only form) from it or whole file only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can load an assembly sent from a remote computer (I will not discuss here security implications of this, I'd - at least - check for a signature):

```
var data = new WebClient.DownloadData(url); // For example...
var assembly = Assembly.Load(data);
```

In C++/CLI (it's not clear in your question what's language you're using):

```
array<Byte>^ data = (gcnew WebClient())->DownloadData(url);
Assembly^ assembly = Assembly::Load(data);
```

Now you have assembly and you can load something from it, for example (just for illustration):

```
var plugins = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
    .Where(x => typeof(IYourContract).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAbstract)
    .Select(x => (IYourContract)Activator.CreateInstance(x));
```

Please note that this is a very naive implementation because each instance will be different (if you load same plugin multiple times) and it's also expansive in terms of resources (primary memory). You should keep an assembly cache:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Assembly> _cachedAssemblies =
    new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();

public static Assembly LoadRemoteAssembly(string url)
{
    lock (_cachedAssemblies)
    {
        if (_cachedAssemblies.ContainsKey(url))
            return _cachedAssemblies[url];

        var data = new WebClient.DownloadData(url); // For example...
        var assembly = Assembly.Load(data);

        _cachedAssemblies.Add(url, assembly);

        return assembly;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. So, I will download it with WebClient, but to the memory? One more question: can I load only one class(only form) from it or whole file only?

Comment: @Michail yes, that's it. Please take care to do not download and load in memory the same assembly more than once (to avoid weird behaviors this _may_ produce and to reduce memory usage). No, you can't load just one type, if you download one assembly it'll be fully loaded in memory (but JIT compiler will be smart enough to compile only what needed). Please note that dependencies must be available also client side. There are other techniques to achieve similar results but I can't be more specific without much more detailed context.

Comment: There is more details: It is central toolbox. After authenticating user i am configuring it by using specified modules only. Some of modules can be placed on remote stations. I want to avoid to load not necessary things and reduce network load. I can not know upfront the size of future modules. They will be added during whole life circle of the application. Can it be done by other methods, comparing WebClient?

Comment: If it's a configuration tool you may _download_ only its definition. User interface may be built client side dynamically without a deep knowledge what what it is configuring. As alternative remote modules may send to client only a small assembly with minimal logic and user interface for configuration. In this case they'll be downloaded on demand (or in a background thread) and **cached** locally (refresh is required only if assembly version number changes).

Comment: Client first query version (using another URL a Web Service or with query parameters) and remote modules answers with a qualified assembly name. If it doesn't exist in cache (or version is different) then new download starts, assembly is saved to disk locally (and from disk loaded) and it won't be overwritten unless version changes again in future.

Comment: for example it's a Form in assembly and other stuff. I want to "have"(download probably) only form's class, make instance and run. What to you mean "only its definition"? What do you mean "may be built client side dynamically"? And it is good idea to make small assembly. Need to think about it, but i want to keep all in one file for more easy version control. But thank you in any way.

Comment: You can't download only few types from an assembly (it's all or nothing). You you MAY do is to split assembly in modules and download only required modules (but, trust me, this will make things even more complicate). To keep UI separate from logic is a pretty good thing (honestly I don't see how to have two assemblies in your version control can make it more complicate to manage).

Comment: Dynamically generated UI: Imagine you have a file where you say: "configuration field X, type: string, validation: ABC". You download this and you build UI dynamically without knowing more details. Drawbacks: it's less _pretty_ and harder to startup but no code to download and pretty small. Think about Windows Policy Editor. Another way is to _describe_ UI in, for example, XML. You download and parse XML to build UI locally, client side. Similar to what TFS does.

Comment: but will actions on the form still work after deserialization? It will be only Form without logic inside. I think, what you first solution is good enough. I just need to keep assemblies as small as possible, how i should normally should do. Thank you.

Comment: If you download just "description" then there is no logic (or small logic or...XML logic like for msbuild). Of course if you use assemblies you can download logic and UI all together.

Comment: one more question: it is possible to read "qualified assembly name" before downloading without making "API" for requesting it from server?

Comment: Yes with some work both server and client side. You can put such information in HTTP headers. You start a request and after you have headers you abort it if you don't need it.